# Creating a dummy code 0-1 if column name in one of two ID columns

Tags: r, join

I have two ID columns in a dataframe. I want to create a number of dummy codes so that each unique ID represents a column with a 0 or 1 depending on whether that ID is in EITHER ID column 1 or 2. So something like this:

```
    ID1   ID2 TEST1 TEST2 TEST3 TEST4 TEST5
1 TEST1 TEST2     1     1     0     0     0
2 TEST2 TEST3     0     1     1     0     0
3 TEST3 TEST4     0     0     1     1     0
4 TEST4 TEST5     0     0     0     1     1
```

This is what I've been trying without success.

```
df_1 <- df %>% mutate(weight=1, ID3=df$ID1) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols=c(ID1, ID2), names_from=ID3, 
              values_from=weight, values_fn=mean, 
              values_fill=NA)

df_2 <- df %>% mutate(weight=1, ID3=df$ID2) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols=c(ID1, ID2), names_from=ID3, 
              values_from=weight, values_fn=mean, 
              values_fill=NA)
```

I was trying to create two dataframes, one with dummy codes built out based on ID1 and one based on ID2, and then using those two dataframes in a fulljoin but the join is either producing a dataframe with suffixes or only pulling data from one of the dfs.

### data

```
df <- data.frame(ID1=c("TEST1", "TEST2", "TEST3", "TEST4"), 
                 ID2=c("TEST2", "TEST3", "TEST4", "TEST5"))

## expected result
data.frame(ID1=c("TEST1", "TEST2", "TEST3", "TEST4"), 
           ID2=c("TEST2", "TEST3", "TEST4", "TEST5"), 
           TEST1=c(1, 0, 0, 0), TEST2=c(1, 1, 0, 0), TEST3=c(0, 1, 1, 0), 
           TEST4=c(0, 0, 1, 1), TEST5=c(0, 0, 0, 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by first identifying all the unique values in `ID1 and` ID2`by finding the`union()` of them:

```r
df <- data.frame(ID1=c("TEST1", "TEST2", "TEST3", "TEST4"), 
                 ID2=c("TEST2", "TEST3", "TEST4", "TEST5"))
unid <- union(df$ID1, df$ID2)
```

Next, you could loop over those values (with `lapply()`) each time finding whether `ID1` or `ID2` is equal to the particular value.  Then, set the names of the resulting list to the values of the unique IDs.

```r
ids <- lapply(unid, \(i)as.numeric(df$ID1 == i | df$ID2 == i))
names(ids) <- unid
```

Finally, pull everything back together by making the list into a data frame.

```r
do.call(data.frame, ids)
#>   TEST1 TEST2 TEST3 TEST4 TEST5
#> 1     1     1     0     0     0
#> 2     0     1     1     0     0
#> 3     0     0     1     1     0
#> 4     0     0     0     1     1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Using `match` with `tabulate`

```
> d |> cbind(sapply(d, match, ids) |> apply(1, tabulate, nbins=length(ids)) |> 
+              `rownames<-`(ids) |> t())
    ID1   ID2 TEST1 TEST2 TEST3 TEST4 TEST5
1 TEST1 TEST2     1     1     0     0     0
2 TEST2 TEST3     0     1     1     0     0
3 TEST3 TEST4     0     0     1     1     0
4 TEST4 TEST5     0     0     0     1     1
```

or with `rowTabulates` (faster!).

```
> d |> cbind(vapply(d, match, ids, FUN.VALUE=1:4) |>
+              matrixStats::rowTabulates(nbins=length(ids)) |> `colnames<-`(ids))
    ID1   ID2 TEST1 TEST2 TEST3 TEST4 TEST5
1 TEST1 TEST2     1     1     0     0     0
2 TEST2 TEST3     0     1     1     0     0
3 TEST3 TEST4     0     0     1     1     0
4 TEST4 TEST5     0     0     0     1     1
```

Brief demonstration what `match` and `tabulate` are doing:

```
> match(3, 1:4)
[1] 3
> tabulate(3, nbins=4)
[1] 0 0 1 0
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(d)
structure(list(ID1 = c("TEST1", "TEST2", "TEST3", "TEST4"), ID2 = c("TEST2", 
"TEST3", "TEST4", "TEST5")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
> ids <- d[1:2] |> unlist() |> unique() |> sort()
```